# supervisorctl add & remove commands

Tags: process-management, supervisord

## Context

In the [supervisor documentation](http://supervisord.org/running.html#supervisorctl-actions), I can read the following parameters, for the `supervisorctl add` and `supervisorctl remove` control commands:

> add <name> […]
>
> Activates any updates in config for process/group

> remove <name> […]
>
> Removes process/group from active config

## Problem

I am not sure to get what it means concretely for the processes running on the system to "activate" an update in config, neither to "remove" a process/group from "active config".

## Question

What do these two commands exactly do?

- when no supervisord config file has been modified beforehand?
- when config files have been modified prior to using these? (both when `supervisorctl reread` has been used and not)

### Bonus (optional) question

- Does `supervisorctl update` internally uses `remove` and `add`? If so, how?